# Problem getting native code to work in a module in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to build an Android library that has a combo of native code and Java code calling the C++ code. The C++ is stictly limited to the library. I managed to get a project compiling, but when I launch the unit testing, I get an exception that it cannot find the library.
I checked and the code does generate the .so files, but they just can't be found.

So, I created an empty activity project and created in it a module for an Android library.
In it, I placed my code in the `src/main/cpp` directory, along with a `CMakeLists.txt` file:
`libnative.cpp`:

```
#include "libnativeJNI.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL GEN_FUNCNAME(TestFunction)(JNIEnv *jenv, jobject jobj)
{
    return 0;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`libnative.h`:

```
#ifndef NDKTROUBLESHOOT_LIBNATIVEJNI_H
#define NDKTROUBLESHOOT_LIBNATIVEJNI_H

#include "jni.h"
#define GEN_FUNCNAME(FUNCNAME) Java_com_java_libnative_libnative_##FUNCNAME

#endif //NDKTROUBLESHOOT_LIBNATIVEJNI_H
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project("LibNative")
add_library(LibNative SHARED libnativeJNI.cpp)
find_library(log-lib log)
target_link_libraries(LibNative ${log-lib})
```

I also updated gradle inside the module to compile the native code by adding the following lines in the `android` section:

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
```

The native code is linked to the Java class in `src/main/java/com/java/libnative/`:
`libnative.java`:

```
package com.java.libnative;

public class libnative {
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("LibNative");
    }

    private native int TestFunction();

    public libnative()
    {
        TestFunction();
    }
}
```

I can also see the native code being compiled in a library as `libnative/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/{Architecture}/libLibNative.so`.

Now, the IDE recognizes the native functions, but I created a unit test in the module to test if it actually works:

```
package com.java.libnative;
import org.junit.Test;

public class UnitTest {
    @Test
    public void library_canLoad()
    {
        new libnative();
    }
}
```

However, doing so triggers an exception on run:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libnative in java.library.path
```

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: The test you've shown looks like a local unit test. Such tests are run directly on your computer (in a JVM), not on an Android device or in an Android emulator. Perhaps there is a way to get `System.loadLibrary` to work from within such a test, but I'm not sure I see the usefulness of testing `System.loadLibrary`(?).

Comment: Ok, so I should try to do that test in the app rather than the unit test then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, as mentioned by [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1524450/michael), that the test environment doesn't support the loading of a native library. I tested the same code by sending it to a phone bundled in an app and it worked fine.
Therefore in this case, the unit testing cannot be used to test the library unfortunately.